# symfony 1.4 doctrine 1.2 - create userfriendly query/update

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony1, doctrine-1.2

I have table in mysql:

```
id | num1 | num2| num 3| num3| num5|
1  | 6    | 3   | 4    | 2   | 1   |
```

in sql I do for example:

```
$num = num2; 
$val = 2;
$id  = 2;

$sql = "update TABLE set '$num'='$val' where id='$id'";
mysql_query( $sql);
```

I can do with `$val` and `$id`, but I have a problem with `$num`...

how to do this in Doctrine 1.2?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->update('TABLE')
    ->set($num, '?', $val)
    ->where('id = ?', $id)
    ->execute();
```